# Différence entre un groupe participial et un groupe adjectival

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, adverbes, participe-présent, participe-passé

J'ai un exercice de grammaire dans lequel je dois identifier la nature et la fonction de groupe de mots. J'hésite entre groupe adjectival et groupe participial.

> Lorsque je suis **fatiguée de la grisaille routinière**, je me mets à rêver d'un lac calme et lisse dans lequel ...

Ma réponse :

> Groupe participial, Attribut du sujet (avec *suis*).

Le groupe à identifier commence par un participe passé et le participe passé est employé seul dans ce groupe, ce qui me fait douter ; ce pourait être un groupe adjectival et non un groupe participial ?

Answer (score 3):

La différence entre le groupe participial et le groupe adjectival est que le groupe participial contient toujours un participe *présent* alors que le groupe adjectival contient un adjectif, qui peut être un participe passé employé comme adjectif.

Selon le site *Allô prof*, [le groupe participial](http://bv.alloprof.qc.ca/francais/la-grammaire-de-la-phrase/les-groupes-de-mots/le-groupe-participial.aspx) :

> Le groupe participial est un groupe syntaxique dont le noyau est un participe présent.
>   [...]
>   On reconnaît le groupe participial par le verbe au participe présent qui l'introduit.

Le groupe adjectival peut avoir trois fonctions :

- Il est complément du nom lorsqu'il est placé à côté du nom.

> Sa *fille* **cadette** va à l'université.

- Il est attribut du sujet lorsqu'il suit un verbe attributif (être, sembler, avoir l'air, etc.) et attribut une caractéristique à un nom sujet.

> Ma mère semble **préoccupée**.

- Il est attribut du complément direct lorsqu'il suit un complément direct qui, lui, complète un verbe.

> Ce plan semble une idée **géniale**.

Le groupe participial peut avoir deux fonctions :

- Il est attribut du complément direct du verbe lorsqu'il introduit un attribut au complément direct.

> Je suis une femme **aimant chanter**.

Il peut aussi être complément du nom.

> Ce stylet **permettant de tracer des formes complexes** est une invention de mon père.

---

Donc, le groupe de l'exemple est effectivement un groupe attribut du sujet (attribut du pronom *je* avec verbe attributif *être*), mais il s'agit d'un groupe adjectival puisque le participe passé est employé comme adjectif. Il ne peut pas être groupe participial, car le participe n'est pas un participe présent.

Comment: Au fait, j'ai trouvé [un article](http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/igram_0222-9838_1989_num_41_1_1998) intéressant et je pense qu'il n'y aucune raison de distinguer participe passés et participes présents. Quant à une éventuelle distinction entre groupe participial et groupe adjectival, ça me parait assez artificiel (pour ne pas dire inutile).